# Nothing visible inside ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular5, ngfor

I am trying to pull data from Firebase and display it on my page but everything nested inside my ngFor is not showing, any ideas why?

My page currently looks like this but I want the data inside the ul to actually show

[image]

**shop-items-list.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let shopItem of shopItems">
      <div>
        <h2>TESTING 2.0</h2>
        <h1>{{shopItem.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{shopItem.price}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**shop-items-list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ShopItem } from '../../models/shopItem';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop-items-list',
  templateUrl: './shop-items-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shop-items-list.component.css']
})
export class ShopItemsListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  shopItems: ShopItem[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." (keyup)="search(input.value)" #input>
<app-shop-items-list [shopItems]="filteredShopItems"></app-shop-items-list>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ShopItem} from './models/shopItem';
import {ShopService} from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  allShopItems: ShopItem[];
  filteredShopItems: ShopItem[];

  constructor(private service: ShopService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.findAllShopItems()
      .subscribe(
        shopItems => this.allShopItems = this.filteredShopItems = shopItems
      );
  }

  search(search: string) {
    this.filteredShopItems = this.allShopItems.filter(shopItem =>
      shopItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
  }


}
```

**app.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { ShopItem } from './models/shopItem';

@Injectable()
export class ShopService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  findAllShopItems(): Observable<ShopItem[]> {

    return this.af.list('products').valueChanges().map(ShopItem.fromJsonList);

  }

}
```

**shopItem.ts**

```js
export class ShopItem {

  constructor (
    public $key: string,
    public filename: string,
    public name: string,
    public price: number
  ) {}

  static fromJsonList(array): ShopItem[] {
    return array.map(ShopItem.fromJson);
  }

  static fromJson({$key, filename, name, price}): ShopItem {
    return new ShopItem(
      $key,
      filename,
      name,
      price
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: do you see the values in console?

Comment: No I don't see any values in the console how can i check

Comment: add console.log (this.allShopItems) inside subscribe

Comment: I am getting them in the console

Comment: can you post the value of console.log(JSON.stringify(this.allShopItems));

Comment: it returned undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning empty array to **`allShopItems`** instead change it as,

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.findAllShopItems()
      .subscribe(
        shopItems => this.allShopItems = shopItems;
      );
  }

  search(search: string) {
    this.filteredShopItems = this.allShopItems.filter(shopItem =>
      shopItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
```

also try adding **`ngIf`** over **`filteredShopItems`** to make sure data exists

```
<app-shop-items-list *ngIf="filteredShopItems" [shopItems]="filteredShopItems"></app-shop-items-list>
```

Comment: I think I should be able to assign both the allShopItems and filtered

Comment: no need to do that since you are doing that inside the function